# divide string into characters

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have an NSString *titleName which changes according to an if statement. So the length (number of characters) in the string changes.  I would like to divide titleName into a MutableArray of separate strings consisting of its individual characters.  I would then like to use these separate strings as  the text in different UILabels.  I am not sure as how to go about this.

Through some research I have tried to create the NSMutable array like this

```
NSMutableArray *letterArray = substringWithRange:((i = 0);i<[titleName2 length];i++));
```

but this gives me an error Use of undeclared identifier 'substringWithRange.

Can someone help me.

I decided to use componentsSeparatedByString instead and just created my various strings with a , between each letter.  Thanks for anybody's thoughts though.

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted is not valid objective-C.
To keep the same algorithm you should write something like :

```
NSMutableArray *letterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger length = [titleName2 length];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    [letterArray addObject:[titleName2 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably much "cheaper" to hold a C-array of `unichar` characters that make-up the string.  It will also be quicker to create:

```
NSString *input = @"How now brown cow?";
unichar chars[[input length]];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [input length]; i++)
    chars[i] = [input characterAtIndex:i];
```

Alternatively you could use `malloc()` to create the C-array:

```
NSString *input = @"How now brown cow?";
unichar *chars = (unichar *)malloc([input length]);
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [input length]; i++)
    chars[i] = [input characterAtIndex:i];
```

and then use `free()`, later, to, err, free the memory:

```
free(chars);
```

Cheaper still, would be to not split-up the string at all...

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
NSMutableArray *letterArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0;i<[titleName2 length];i++)
{
    [letterArray addObject: [titleName2 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)]];
}

DLog(@"%@", letterArray);
```

Other option to get characters of string

```
NSMutableArray *letterArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i=0; i < [titleName2 length]; i++)
{
    [letterArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [titleName2 characterAtIndex:i]]];
}

DLog(@"characters - %@", letterArray);
```